# Active Admin create additional URL on unique field

Tags: activeadmin

I have an object Foo which has fields id and token (both are unique, both have db indexes). I want to be able to get to Foo 1 by going to url "/admin/foos/token-of-foo-1" in *addition* to being able to use the url "/admin/foos/1". I know that I will need to do something like the below in my routes.rb, but I'm having trouble. Help?

```
ActiveAdmin.routes(self) # keep this
get 'admin/???', to: 'admin/???' # add ...something
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, some thoughts:

```
#admin/foo.rb
  controller do
    def find_resource
      if params[:id].length == 16 # it's a token
         end_of_association_chain.find_by_token(params[:id])
      else
        end_of_association_chain.find(params[:id])
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of purposes I use this gem called [FriendlyID](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id). You can select which fields should form the URL slug, in your case the field `token`:

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :token, use: :slugged
end
```

Let me know if you have more doubts on how to configure. It has a great integration with Active Admin.

Comment: this gem seems great (and maintained!) but I chose the other answer because I think it is more universally usable